# Laravel Eloquent Relationships - Join Tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

```
    class Withdraw extends Model
    {
    
       public function getUser()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
        }
    
        public function getStatus()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(WithdrawStatus::class, 'status_id', 'id');
        }
    
     public static function getWithDrawList()
        {
            $data = Withdraw::with(['getUser' => function ($q) {
                        $q->select('users.*', 'trainer_details.default_acc_name', 'trainer_details.default_bank_id',
                        'trainer_details.default_acc_number');
                        $q->join('trainer_details', 'users.id', '=', 'trainer_details.user_id');
                    }])
                    ->with(['getStatus'])
                    ->get()
                    ->toArray();      
                    
           return $data;
        }
}
```

**bank table data**

```
id,name
```

**data return by getwithdrawlist**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [user_id] => 2
            [amount] => 200.0000
            [status_id] => 4
            [created_at] => 
            [updated_at] => 2020-09-18T15:53:13.000000Z
            [get_user] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => lim
                    [default_acc_name] => lim
                    [default_bank_id] => 1
                    [default_acc_number] => 123156
                )

            [get_status] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [status] => Rejected
                    [created_at] => 2020-09-18T14:09:41.000000Z
                    [updated_at] => 2020-09-18T14:09:41.000000Z
                )

        )
)
```

**Question**: The above code is to retrieve all the user details, so total need to join 4 tables in order to get the complete data which is **users, withdrawstatus, withdraw, banks**. I have success to link 3 tables together but I failed to join the data with the **banks**. Does it mean that the bank details should return inside array which is **[get_user]**? Does anyone know how to use Laravel relationship to join another table which is **banks** ya? Please advise :((.

Comment: How does the Bank model relate to those existing models?

Answer (score 1):

accordingly to

```
 $data = Withdraw::with(['getUser' => function ($q) {
                        $q->select('users.*', 'trainer_details.default_acc_name', 'trainer_details.default_bank_id',
                        'trainer_details.default_acc_number');
                        $q->join('trainer_details', 'users.id', '=', 'trainer_details.user_id');
                    }])
                    ->with(['getStatus'])
                    ->get()
                    ->toArray();
```

will not retrieve all data you need to do many joins depending on the number of relation you have in your case you have 4 relation so you need at lead 3 joins

```
 $data = Withdraw::with(['getUser' => function ($q) {
                        $q->select('users.*', 'trainer_details.default_acc_name', 'trainer_details.default_bank_id',
                        'trainer_details.default_acc_number');
                        $q->join('trainer_details', 'bank.id', '=', 'trainer_details.user_id');
                        $q->join('trainer_details', put other relation if you have here, '=', 'trainer_details.user_id');
                        
                    }])
                    ->with(['getStatus'])
                    ->get()
                    ->toArray();
```